# Jquery validator alert gets triggered multiple times while press enter only in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery validator triggers alert multiple times in firefox when pressing enter key,

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    var summary = "You have the following errors: \n";
    $.each(errorList, function() {
        summary += " * " + this.message + "\n";
    });
    alert(summary);
    this.defaultShowErrors();
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xTdYr/97/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up your html code, and do things simple.

Use rules option to set up the required inputs.

Visit the documentation of .validate(): http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Answer (score 0):

Validate is oddly doing another processes for `blur` and `keyup`. You have to add those options to validate as false.

```
,
onfocusout:false,
onkeyup:false
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xTdYr/98/)**